# Is there any cycling example for steepest edge pivoting rule in Simplex method, when there is a finite optimal solution

Tags: examples-counterexamples, linear-programming, simplex-method

First, the steepest edge pivot rule is the rule in [A practicable steepest-edge simplex algorithm](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01593804) , and [Steepest-edge simplex algorithms for linear programming](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01581089).

The cycling examples founded, are all unbounded, but the algorithm itself detects unbounded case and stops, thus those are not a true cycling

Unbounded (no solution) example: [Systematic construction of examples for cycling in the simplex method](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0305054805000493)

The example in [Myths and Counterexamples in Mathematical Programming](https://glossary.informs.org/myths/CurrentVersion/myths.pdf#section*.33) is not using steepest rule, but "reduced cost divided by the Euclidean norm of the tableau column vector" , called [A largest-distance pivot rule for the simplex algorithm](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0377221707003098)

Edit: Example 6.1 in [Systematic construction of examples for cycling in the simplex method](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0305054805000493). A debug into Julia code shows that no cycle as `{5, 6, 7}, {1, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 7} {2, 3, 7}, {3, 4, 7}, {4, 5, 7}, {5, 6, 7}`, but `{5, 6, 7}, {1, 6, 7}, {2, 6, 7}` and return with unbounded status.

```
    using StatusSwitchingQP
    using LinearAlgebra

    c = [-7 / 100, -3 / 50, 11 / 50, 133 / 12500]
    G = [33/25 1/2 -53/25 -9/20
        -44 -24/5 6 33/100
        1319/1000 -40 2123/10 1173/100]
    g = [0.0, 0, 0]
    A = zeros(0, 4)
    b = zeros(0)
    P = LP(c, A, b; G=G, g=g)

    #=
    settings = Settings(; rule=:stpEdgeLP)
    ts = @elapsed res = SimplexLP(P; settings=settings)
    println("steepest edge:  ", ts, "  seconds")
    display(res)
    =#

    #Example 6.1, after {5, 6, 7} and {1, 6, 7}, not {1, 2, 7}, but {2, 6, 7}
    status, c, A, b, d, u = cAbdu(P)
    q = [0.0, 0, 0]
    S = Status[DN, DN, DN, DN, IN, IN, IN]
    B = [5, 6, 7]
    invB = Matrix{Float64}(I, 3, 3)
    tol = 2^-26

    iH, x, invB = StatusSwitchingQP.stpEdgeLP(c, A, b, d, u, B, S; invB=invB, q=q, tol=tol)
    display((iH, x, S))
```

more detail: [Steepest-Edge.pdf](https://github.com/maxchendt/FuturesHedge/blob/master/pdf/A-2023-Steepest-Edge.pdf)